# Stopping/starting svnserve locally

Tags: svn, configuration, svnserve

(Developing on Ubuntu)

I'm installing SVN locally to track my project up to its 1.0 release.  Nothing fancy, as I am the sole developer, so no authentication/SSH, etc; nothing with webdav/httpd, etc. Just a plain old local server instance!

I've never done this before, so it finally dawned on me that I would have to manually start and stop svnserve anytime I want to commit any code to a repo.

I see that it is possible to configure inetd to dispatch svnserve as a service. Basically, inetd listens on a port you specify, and if it detects any svn traffic on that port, starts svnserve and passes the commands on to it; it looks like inetd also shuts down servers when they are not being used to conserve memory.

**Any way, inetd or otherwise, to configure svn to start up when a local client tries to hit one of its repositories, and to shut back down automatically when it's done?**

For the sake of my example, here are some pertinent URLs:

*/usr/bin* - where svn, svnadmin and svnserve are all installed
*/opt/sandbox/svn/myProj* - the location of *myProj*'s repository

Thus the clients should be looking to connect to the server by hitting

```
svn://opt/sandbox/svn/myProj
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a server. Just access the repository with `file:///opt/sandbox/...` instead of `svn://`. It's faster, too.

That said, Subversion is getting old. [Try a DVCS](http://hginit.com/). They are as easy to set up and it won't take you more than a minute to share your project later.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I'll check out Mercurial in a little bit. Is there any special config that needs to happen with svnadmin that I need to perform, or will svn play nicely with svnadmin with this file:/// setup?

Comment: Nope. Just `svn checkout` from "file:///" instead of from "svn://". Make sure you use the right the number of slashes.